# Inherited method dependencies using NDepend

Tags: ndepend

The class browser of [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) doesn't seem to have an option for revealing **inherited methods**.

We have a scenario where we have thousands of singly-rooted **Model** objects that descend from **RootModel**, for instance. Only **RootModel** defines **Save()**. How does one form a query for finding all instances where **SampleModel** (:RootModel) invokes **Save()**?

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE IsUsing "SampleModel.Save()" ORDER BY DepthOfIsUsing
```

...is rejected: **Not a valid assembly, namespace, typ, method or field name**.

This seems to be the best approximation but is not exact:

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE IsUsing "SampleModel" AND IsUsing "RootModel.Save()" ORDER BY DepthOfIsUsing
```

This seems like a pretty heavy limitation, no? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

From the static point of view of NDepend the class `SampleModel` doesn't declare a `Save()` method. This is why the first query doesn't compile.

The second query is indeed the good thing to do in your case. To get it right, you can use the [Code Query on LINQ (CQLinq capabilities)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) and rewrite it this way:

```
from m in Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("MyNamespace.RootModel"))
         .ChildMethods()
where m.IsUsing("MyNamespace.RootModel.Save()")
select new { m, m.ParentType }
```

Comment: Hi Patrick; are you suggesting that static analysis alone can't analyze inherited methods or that it's simply not implemented by NDepend? Surely it's the latter: various tools like the reflector enumerate inherited members in class browsers through static analysis. The second query is an estimate at best; it's not the precise answer one would hope for. I see that you guys are quite open to community feedback on NDepend and I’m hopeful that this one makes the list; in my estimation it’s a very common scenario in OOP.